# Drone Suggestion Model - Linux Based

Tags: quadcopters, recommendations

I need to buy a drone like the 3DR Solo that can allow me to program it and work with different features. I mean, I would like to have a drone where I can access towards SSH, I can deploy C scripts (i.e. the executable), the operating system is a Linux based system (that can be configured), it features the MavLink protocol, GPS sensors and so on.
The cheaper it is, the better it is due to budget.

Comment: I don't know of anything that does what you ask for in the question, but could you explain why you want these features? Is it possible that you are a victim of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Maybe something like [Ardupilot](https://ardupilot.org/) does what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably suggest getting a kit and going from there. Something like the HobbyPower F550 that comes with a PixHawk.

Another option would be to get a kit and use the BeagleBone Blue which is designed for robotics tinkering. As seen in the comments there are several open source codebases such as Ardupilot and PX4. MavLink is also open source so you can implement that on the platform of your choice.